# Flexbox not responding?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, formatting, bulma

I'm trying to center these two divs horizontally using bulma and it's just not responding. I've tried flex-row, justified center, align center and nothing it working. What else can I do about this?

```
 **EDIT TO ADD MORE CODE**
```

```html
 <!-- contact form  -->
<section class="contact section is-small">
    <h2 class="contact-header is-size-1"> Contact Me</h2>
    <!-- Form -->
    <div class="contact-form is-flex is-flex-direction-row">
        <div class="form">
            <form>
                <p>Name</p>
                <input type="text" class="input is-normal" placeholder="First Name">
                <input type="text" class="input is-normal" placeholder="Last Name">
                <p>E-mail Address</p>
                <input class="input" type="email" placeholder="E.g. 'john.smith@gmail.com'">
                <p>Message</p>
                <textarea class="fixed size textarea" placeholder="What's up?"></textarea>
                <button class="button">Submit</button>
            </form>
            <div>
                <img src="" class="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Please post enough code so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin thanks for the feedback. I added more code.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.9.3/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="contact-form is-flex is-justify-content-center ">
            <div class="form">
                <form>
                    <p>Name</p>
                    <input type="text" class="input is-normal" placeholder="First Name">
                    <input type="text" class="input is-normal" placeholder="Last Name">
                    <p>E-mail Address</p>
                    <input class="input" type="email" placeholder="E.g. 'john.smith@gmail.com'">
                    <p>Message</p>
                    <textarea class="fixed size textarea" placeholder="What's up?"></textarea>
                    <button class="button">Submit</button>
                </form>
                <div>
                    <img src="" class="">
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: that didn't work but I add more code to op

Answer (score -1):

This will help you

```
 <div class="contact-form is-flex is-flex-direction-column is-justify-content-center is-align-items-center">
            <div class="form">
                <form>
                    <p>Name</p>
                    <input type="text" class="input is-normal" placeholder="First Name">
                    <input type="text" class="input is-normal" placeholder="Last Name">
                    <p>E-mail Address</p>
                    <input class="input" type="email" placeholder="E.g. 'john.smith@gmail.com'">
                    <p>Message</p>
                    <textarea class="fixed size textarea" placeholder="What's up?"></textarea>
                    <button class="button">Submit</button>
                </form>
                <div>
                    <img src="" class="">
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div>
          <img src="" class="" />
        </div>
```

Comment: that didn't work but I add more code to op